# When is the rendering context created in opengl with Qt?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, opengl

I am trying out OpenGL with Qt. I compiled the [2dpainting example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/opengl-2dpainting.html) from Qt's documentation. In the example are two animations side by side, one which runs natively and the other one gets rendered by OpenGL. I do not see a difference though. How can I make sure, that the hardware accelerator is used. I am running the example on an embedded device with Ångström Linux.

I added a line to the constructor of the opengl widget, to determine the renderer that is used, but the function always returns a NULL pointer.

```
GLWidget::GLWidget(Helper *helper, QWidget *parent)
     : QGLWidget(QGLFormat(QGL::SampleBuffers), parent), helper(helper)
 {
        elapsed = 0;
        setFixedSize(200, 200);
        setAutoFillBackground(false);
        printf("  OpenGL Renderer:   %s\n",glGetString(GL_RENDERER)); //added this line

 }
```

Now I read in numerous online forums, that I need a valid rendering context. But what does this mean, and when is it created when using Qt? I tried putting the same function in all the other functions of the GLWidget, but without any luck.

Comment: what hardware, the video driver has opengl support?

Comment: @neagoegab: [Texas Instrument DM3730](http://www.ti.com/product/dm3730?DCMP=D%252520DSPS%252520DSPS&CMP=KNC-GoogleTI&247SEM) It actually has only support for OpenGLES 1.1 and 2.0, OpenVG1.0, but the Qt example compiled and ran without a problem. That's why I am trying to find out what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is initialized as late as possible, i.e. when something actually needs to be drawn.

From the [`QGLWidget::paintEvent()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qglwidget.html#paintEvent) docs:

> Handles paint events passed in the event parameter. Will cause the virtual paintGL() function to be called.
>   The widget's rendering context will become the current context **and initializeGL() will be called if it hasn't already been called**.

Comment: Does this mean, that the rendering context gets destroyed after paintEvent() is called?

Comment: Not necessarily. But it's only fully initialized the first time something needs to be painted. It should always be available in the `paintGL` virtual you're supposed to be overriding.

Answer (score 1):

The openGL scene is rendered in the QGlWidget [paintGL](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qglwidget.html#paintGL) function, you generally need to derive from QGlWidget with your own paintGL function

The NeHe tutorials have been [adapted for Qt](http://www.digitalfanatics.org/projects/qt_tutorial/chapter14.html)